# How to properly add to a variable, which is constantly updated using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a fillRect which I am trying to move vertically every time an input value is updated. My issue, is that for some weird reason, once the input value reaches 10, the y-margin jumps. Why is that?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domloaded, false);

function domloaded() {

  //variables for canvas API
  var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  function draw() {
    //GET current Yposition
    var yPos = document.getElementById('yPos').value;
    var y = 1 + yPos;
    //remove previous canvas, necessary to reiterate
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);
    //drawing
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(200, y, 200, 55);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  draw();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
input,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5% 0;
  background: red;
}
#control {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#view {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Book Canvas Demo</h1>
    <div id="control">
      <h1 class="floatLeft">Y Position:</h1>
      <input id="yPos" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="500" value="0" class="floatLeft">
    </div>
    <div id="view">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In other words, how do I properly add to a value, which is constantly updated using a requestAnimationFrame. Thank you.

Comment: `var y = 1 + parseInt(yPos,10);`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `yPos` as a number, but in fact it's a string. The in my opinion easiest method to convert anything to a number is using a unary plus in front:

```
    var yPos = +document.getElementById('yPos').value;
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domloaded, false);

function domloaded() {

  //variables for canvas API
  var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  function draw() {
    //GET current Yposition
    var yPos = +document.getElementById('yPos').value;
    var y = 1 + yPos;
    //remove previous canvas, necessary to reiterate
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);
    //drawing
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(200, y, 200, 55);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
  draw();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
input,
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5% 0;
  background: red;
}
#control {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
#view {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Book Canvas Demo</h1>
    <div id="control">
      <h1 class="floatLeft">Y Position:</h1>
      <input id="yPos" type="number" step="1" min="0" max="500" value="0" class="floatLeft">
    </div>
    <div id="view">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```